# Drill JDBC and Zookeeper throws UnresolvedAddressException

Tags: java, docker, mesos, apache-drill, dcos

Im trying to connect externally to a containerized distributed apache drill setup on DC/OS using the JDBC driver as shown here

https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-the-jdbc-driver/#example-of-connecting-to-drill-programmatically

However, when running this outside of the cluster to connect from my machine, the zookeeper connection completes, then it tries to resolve a Drillbit address in the form of

`2d7f7217340c:31010`

where `2d7f7217340c` is the internal drillbit id as shown in the drill web console

which of course throws

`java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException`

until I make an entry in my local `/etc/hosts` file 
to resolve `2d7f7217340c` to the public ip of the drill node.

I've searched around quite a bit on the topic and not found anything. 
Is there a way to configure Zookeeper or Drill to return an IP rather than the drillbit ID so that the hosts file doesn't need to be manually updated?

Comment: Did you specify the following string?
`Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:drill:zk=
PUBLIC_IP:2181/drill/my_cluster_com-drillbits");`
Where PUBLIC_IP is yours public ip address, where drillbit is running.

Comment: yes I have 
`connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:drill:zk=<zk_public_ip>:<zk_port>/drill/<cluster_id>");`
the jdbc connection works when running it on a node in the cluster, but requires the mentioned host file edit when running outside the cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the address string `2d7f7217340c` is defined by the container ID generated during deployment.  Even with modifying the hostname of the container via

`lsns`

`nsenter --target <container_pid> --uts hostname <public_ip>`

and restarting drill in the container, zookeeper still returns the `2d7f7217340c` address.

A working solution is to modify the recent addition of the `DRILL_HOSTNAME` variable in `apache-drill/conf/drill-env.sh` to grab the public hostname via the AWS metadata service

```
export DRILL_HOSTNAME=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname`
```

the public hostname is now advertised by Drill, and can be resolved both externally and internally